# Only half the unwrap of a character's head happens. How to fix?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

The image shows the results of trying to unwrap this character's head. Only half of the unwrap is displayed. The seams are in the right place according to the tutorial. How do I solve this problem?

[image: The image shows the results of trying to unwrap this character's head. Only half of the unwrap is displayed. The seams are in the right place according to the tutorial. How do I solve this problem?]

Comment: You have to apply the mirror modifier first.

Comment: Thank you very much, FFeller!